# Prove that a metric defined on Unitary Space is a metric space

Tags: solution-verification, metric-spaces

I was given an exercise which went like:

> Let $X=\mathbb{C}^n, n\in\mathbb{N}$ and
> $d\left(\xi,\eta\right)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\left\lvert\xi_i-\eta_i\right\rvert^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$,
> where $\xi=\left(\xi_1,\xi_2,\cdots,\xi_n\right)\in
> > X,\eta=\left(\eta_1,\eta_2,\cdots,\eta_n\right)\in X$. Show that $\left(X,d\right)$ is a metric space.

Now, I was able to show $d\left(\xi,\eta\right)\geq0, \forall \xi,\eta\in X$. Also, $d\left(\xi,\eta\right)=0$ iff $\xi=\eta$. I also showed that $d\left(\xi,\eta\right)=d\left(\eta,\xi\right)$. For the third condition (i.e. $d\left(\xi,\eta\right)\leq d\left(\xi,\gamma\right)+d\left(\gamma,\eta\right)$ where $\xi=\left(\xi_1,\xi_2,\cdots,\xi_n\right)\in X$), I proceeded like the following:

Let $\xi_i=a_i+i\cdot b_i$, $\eta_i=c_i+i\cdot d_i$, $\gamma_i=e_i+i\cdot f_i$, where $\xi_i,\eta_i,\gamma_i\in\mathbb{C}$; $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i,e_i,f_i\in\mathbb{R}$. Then
$$\left(d\left(\xi,\eta\right)\right)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\left\lvert\xi_i-\eta_i\right\rvert^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\left\{\left(a_i-c_i\right)^2+\left(b_i-d_i\right)^2\right\}\\
\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\left\{\left(a_i-e_i\right)^2+\left(b_i-f_i\right)^2\right\}+\sum_{i=1}^n\left\{\left(e_i-c_i\right)^2+\left(f_i-d_i\right)^2\right\}\\
=\sum_{i=1}^n\left\lvert\xi_i-\gamma_i\right\rvert^2+\sum_{i=1}^n\left\lvert\gamma_i-\eta_i\right\rvert^2=\left(d\left(\xi,\gamma\right)\right)^2+\left(d\left(\gamma,\eta\right)\right)^2\\
\leq\left(d\left(\xi,\gamma\right)+d\left(\gamma,\eta\right)\right)^2\\
\implies d\left(\xi,\eta\right)\leq d\left(\xi,\gamma\right)+d\left(\gamma,\eta\right)
$$

However, I am not so confident that this solution is right. Is this the case? Also, I feel like there should be a better solution to it, so can someone give me some hints here.

Comment: Your proof seems good to me. Another way is to show that this is just the standard Euclidian metric on $\mathbb{C}^n\simeq \mathbb{R}^{2n}$. (Use the identification $(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n)\mapsto (a_1,b_1,\dots,a_n,b_n)$, where $\xi_j=a_j+ib_j$.)

Comment: @Laci I haven't yet learned that stuff...

Comment: Oh, sorry. Your proof is good. If you havent learned about the standard Euclidian metric then I guess this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest way to solve this is using the [Minkowski inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality) which, when specialised to sequences by using the counting measure, will directly give, in my case:

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\left\lvert\xi_i-\eta_i\right\rvert^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\leq\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\left\lvert\xi_i-\gamma_i\right\rvert^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\left\lvert\gamma_i-\eta_i\right\rvert^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: I think using such a strong theorem as minkowski inequality is like killing a fly with a cannon. Showing that the map above is a distance function is an elementary excercise, while proving the Minkowski inequality is hard.